# ERROR: Cannot declare variable inside @interface or @protocol

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, xcode4, xcode4.2

I clicked Modernize Project and then I got some compile errors.  (I Did take a snapshot)

The error is:  Cannot declare variable inside @interface or @protocol

Here is the code in copy and paste format.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "AJHBezierUtils.h"

@interface NSBezierPath (WBBezierPath) 

NSBezierPath        *flattenPath;

NSPointArray        points;

int                 numPoints;


+(NSBezierPath*)roundedPath:(NSRect)aRect radius2:(int)rad2;


-(NSPoint ) getLinePoints:(NSPoint )p1 p2:(NSPoint)p2  withDistance:(int )pointDistance;

- (NSPoint *)pointsFromPathWithDistance:(int)distance numberOfPoints:(int *)numberOfPoints;


- (float)distanceBetweenPoint:(NSPoint)a andPoint:(NSPoint)b;

- (int)numberOfPoints;
```

[image: Here is the error in XCode]

Answer (score 11):

You need braces for interface ivars:

```
@interface NSBezierPath (WBBezierPath)
{
  NSBezierPath        *flattenPath;
  NSPointArray        points;
  int                 numPoints;
}
```

However, because you are defining a category, ivars are not allowed. You need to use properties instead:

```
@interface NSBezierPath (WBBezierPath)

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSBezierPath *flattenPath;

/* Methods */

@end
```

Comment: Exactly what I was just typing, you beat me to it ;)

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick responses!  I did that.....but that generated even more errors....  will post screenshot.                     http://screencast.com/t/B1pfn3yPlKor

Comment: In your new screenshot, you put a close-brace ("}") instead of an open-brace ("{"). And if you hadn't hidden the first error tag, I'm sure it tells you exactly that.

Comment: Sorry that was just a careless mistake.  Fixed the Brace Issue.. and got this:  [link](http://screencast.com/t/khfHcEaTGS2) http://screencast.com/t/khfHcEaTGS2

Comment: I have amended my answer for your special case.